# Best way to upgrade from Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 to ver. 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, ce-1.9.1.0, ce-1.9.2.4

1. I am not ready to upgrade my live production store to Magento 2.1.0 yet. Would you think it would be a good idea to **upgrade from my current version 1.9.1.0 to the latest pre-2.x version (1.9.2.4)** and *why*?
2. What is the best way to do this upgrade? I have a software installation program in cPanel called SOFTACULOUS (and they sent me a link saying an upgrade is available)....I assume it would also be possible to do a "one-click" kind of an upgrade by using Magento Connect? But I read somewhere that "By default the Connect Manager is used to upgrade 3rd party extensions and not core magento" - how do I do this then? Download some kind of a patch and simply upload those files using FTP?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**It depends** on how much customizations do you have? what extensions?

It may be a good move to 1.9.2.4 as it will fix some bugs & security issues.

BUT it can produce other bugs too! because some files are being overwritten.

No Migration Tool can transfer the extensions safely. They only migrate the data. Like:
“LitExtension: Magento to Magento Migration Tool”

You should check your extensions, their compatibility issues,  [1.9.2.4 release notes](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.4.html)  & 
 Consider is it worth for your shop to do this or not.

You may need a developer support in case of the extensions failure. So remember to backup everything first.

Comment: Just a calendar from Amasty - that's all. And a card message enabled.